# OneVsRestClassifier and multi_class="ovr" score when using LogisticRegression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Why `OneVsRestClassifier()` returns much lower score for the same dataset than  just using `multi_class="ovr"` parameter?

Using simple way to fit and get score with logisitc regression:

```
#Load Data, assign variables
training_data = pd.read_csv("iris.data")

training_data.columns = [
  "sepal_length",
  "sepal_width",
  "petal_length",
  "petal_width",
  "class",
]

feature_cols = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width"]
label_cols = ["class"]
X = training_data.loc[:, feature_cols]
y = training_data.loc[:, label_cols].values.ravel()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

# Instantiate and fit the model:
logreg =LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear", multi_class="ovr", random_state=24)
clf = logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
# See if the model is reasonable.
print("Score: ", clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

I get score `0.92` and when using `OneVsAllRegression` I get score of `0.62`

```
training_data = pd.read_csv("iris.data")

training_data.columns = [
  "sepal_length",
  "sepal_width",
  "petal_length",
  "petal_width",
  "class",
]

feature_cols = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width"]
label_cols = ["class"]
X = training_data.loc[:, feature_cols]
y = training_data.loc[:, label_cols].values.ravel()

#transform lables to 0-1-2
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(training_data.loc[:, label_cols].values.ravel())
y=le.transform(training_data.loc[:, label_cols].values.ravel())

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = 3



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)


# Instantiate and fit the model:
logreg = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear", random_state=24))
clf = logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
# See if the model is reasonable.
print("Score: ", clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Is there a reason why one method works way better than the other?

Here how the data input looks like (its the Iris dataset):

`training_data`

```
  sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width     class
       4.9       3.0         1.4            0.2       Iris-setosa
       4.7       3.2         1.3            0.2       Iris-setosa
   (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the score should be the same.
The problem is that for the second method, you binarize the output. This transforms `y` in a way that it changes the prediction. Try `clf.predict(X_test)` to see that the prediction has an incorrect format.

To correct your problem, remove the line:

```
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
```

Then, to have the same score between multiple methods also add a random state when you use `train_test_split`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=24)
```

---

To answer your comments:

If you want to work with labels binarized by `label_binarize()`, you can. Keep the line

```
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
```

And after fitting the model, calculate y_score like this:

```
# Instantiate and fit the model:
logreg = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear", random_state=24))
y_score = logreg.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

The difference with your code is the call of `.decision_function(X_test)` that computes a score for each class. To understand the result, display `y_score`.

Then, your data has a good format to continue the tutorial.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing out what might be causing the difference. What if I need the output to be in that binary/dummy form?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py and it seems that in ordere to get data fro ROC_CURVE plot I need to input it in that kind of form.

Comment: But what do I use y_score  for? As in how it compares to the `clf.score` in my code?

Comment: Due to the call of `decision_function()`, `y_score` contains a prediction score for each label. It is necessary to plot the ROC curve in your tutorial. If you want to compare it to the `clf.score` in your code, compute the predictions that have the max score with `np.argmax(y_score,axis=1)` and compare it to `y_test` (in the same format) with `accuracy_score()`.